How to do an overflow visible in a custom filter with AgGgrid React
I want to do an overflow visible in a custom filter with AgGgrid React.
But Idk how to do it. I have a custom filter in AgGrid React with a DropDownList, but I cannot show by default the options of the DropDown, because it has a overflow scroll and I dont know how to do it visible.
This is how it looks
This is the custom filter (testFilter.tsx)
import {
  IAfterGuiAttachedParams,
  IDoesFilterPassParams,
} from "ag-grid-community";
import { CustomFilterProps, useGridFilter } from "ag-grid-react";
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Dropdown, Input } from "semantic-ui-react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledDropdown = styled.div`
  z-index: 1050;
  .ui.dropdown {
    width: 100%;
  }
  padding: 4px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: visible;

  .ag-menu {
    overflow-y: visible !important;
  }
`;

export default ({ model, onModelChange, getValue }: CustomFilterProps) => {
  const refInput = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [closeFilter, setCloseFilter] = useState<(() => void) | undefined>();

  const [options, setOptions] = useState([
    { key: "option1", text: "Option 1", value: "option1" },
    { key: "option2", text: "Option 2", value: "option2" },
    { key: "option3", text: "Option 3", value: "option3" },
    { key: "option4", text: "Option 4", value: "option4" },
    { key: "option5", text: "Option 5", value: "option5" },
    { key: "option6", text: "Option 6", value: "option6" },
  ]);

  const doesFilterPass = useCallback(
    (params: IDoesFilterPassParams) => {
      const { node } = params;
      const filterText = model?.toLowerCase() || "";
      const value = getValue(node)?.toString().toLowerCase() || "";
      return value.includes(filterText);
    },
    [getValue, model]
  );

  const afterGuiAttached = useCallback(
    ({ hidePopup }: IAfterGuiAttachedParams) => {
      setCloseFilter(() => hidePopup);
    },
    []
  );

  // register filter handlers with the grid
  useGridFilter({
    doesFilterPass,
    afterGuiAttached,
  });

  const handleDropdownChange = (e, { value }) => {
    //No need to develop this, just need to see all the options overflow: visible.
  };

  return (
    <StyledDropdown>
      <p>Search Initiator</p>
      <Dropdown
        placeholder="Select an option"
        fluid
        selection
        options={options}
        onChange={handleDropdownChange}
        value={model?.filter || ""}
      />
    </StyledDropdown>
  );
};

This is the main file
"use strict";

import { ColDef, GridReadyEvent } from "ag-grid-community";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css";
import React, { StrictMode, useCallback, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import testFilter from "./testFilter";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

interface IOlympicData {
  country: string;
  sport: string;
}

const GridExample = () => {
  const gridStyle = useMemo(() => ({ height: "100%", width: "100%" }), []);
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState<IOlympicData[]>();
  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState<ColDef[]>([
    { field: "country", minWidth: 150, filter: testFilter },
    { field: "sport" },
  ]);
  const defaultColDef = useMemo<ColDef>(() => {
    return {
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 100,
    };
  }, []);

  const onGridReady = useCallback((params: GridReadyEvent) => {
    fetch("https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data: IOlympicData[]) => {
        setRowData(data.slice(0, 10));
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={gridStyle} className={"ag-theme-quartz"}>
      <AgGridReact<IOlympicData>
        rowData={rowData}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!);
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <GridExample />
  </StrictMode>
);

